# Ordering columns of a data frame considering dates - R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame (size:36 rows, 2000 columns), which in the last row it contains dates for each column in this format `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.
How can I sort the columns using the dates in the last row?
My attempts so far:

```
df[order(as.Date(df["Dates",], format="%Y-%m-%d")),] 
df[order(lubridate::ymd(df["Dates",])),]
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the `df["Dates",]`  If "Dates' is a column, it should be `df[["Dates"]` or `df[,"Dates"]`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example/expected output to understand the structure.  If we need to order by the last rows `df1[order(as.Date(unlist(tail(df1, 1))))]`

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the last row and do the `order`

```
df1[order(as.Date(unlist(tail(df1, 1))))]
```